# Memory is leaking when I create models in a loop in FuelPHP

Tags: php, memory-leaks, fuelphp

I am running a code like this

```
foreach ($set as $id)
{
    $user = Model_Users::find($id);
    $user = NULL;
}
```

And memory consumption is increased with each loop. Too much to ignore - around 300Kb each time. And number of iterations is hundreds of thousands.

So, there is a question - what I have to destroy or close to keep memory consumption level?

Comment: actually, i also noticed that on some of my codes while using the ORM\Model, this static method is slow, thats why i changed some of my codes to just `DB::methods` classes instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I endeavored a *proper* model, with has_many, observers and stuff. It would be a pity to dump all this job and start over. Speed is not a concern here.

Comment: yeah, i thought so too, it would be a waste not to use all those things you have already in your setup (relationships, observers, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

The v1 ORM caches every model that gets created. Performing a query in a loop is also not the best way to go as if you have "hundreds of thousands" you will be performing hundreds of thousands of queries.

If you have that many rows to work on at once you have two options. The first is to use the DB class to perform your queries. The second would be to run the loop in smaller batches at a time.

I can also recommend using `IN` to load more than one model at once, cutting the query out of the loop.

```
$users = Model_Users::find('all', array(
    'where' => array(
        array('id', 'IN', $set)
    )
);
```

Comment: The short answer is you can't turn it off easily. If you are using ORM's `Query` object you can use `from_cache(false)` to disable the caching, alternately you can look into the `Model` class' cached object property to wipe them manually. http://github.com/fuel/orm/blob/1.8/develop/classes/model.php#L110 It is generally not advised to use the ORM with large data sets like this as the hydration process is very slow and the abstraction that the ORM provides is often not needed for massive operations. Not saying that is the case for your scenario. As I also mentioned you could look at pagination.

Comment: Again - slowness is not a concern at all. This framework has a command line utility which *intended* for working with large datasets. As well as having common model as a universal interface for the data is a cornerstone of the very ORM idea. What's the point in having a model with relations, observers and stuff if you cannot use it when you need it? All I need is to turn this stupid cache off. I did it already, by means of clearing this very variable you pointed to, but rather barbaric way, I am afraid. The question is *why* can't I turn it off easily.

Comment: I really sorry for the harsh responses, but for some reason you always trying to move away from the topic and solve non-existent problems instead. And it's damn hot here, that made me a bit inadequate. My apologies.

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us. The reason no easy or "nice" way of doing this exists is that it simply was not thought of when the code was originally built. The v1 ORM is not the best written when you start to want to do things that it was not designed for it becomes very hard or impossible. With the v2 rewrite this is something we are looking to address. For example the caching in v2 you can turn on or off or switch out the functionality entirely if you wanted to use memcache or w/e